# Mysql: slow down with order by, global database problem

Tags: mysql, order-by, performance, slow-log

i create nasty query for testing reasons. Only for speed testing.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT m.post_id
FROM wp_postmeta m
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta mi ON
m.`post_id` = mi.`post_id`
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta md ON
(md.`post_id` = m.`post_id` AND md.meta_key = "my_test_data_demo_1")
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta mf ON
(mf.`post_id` = m.`post_id` AND mf.meta_key = "my_test_data_demo_2")
WHERE (m.meta_key = "my_test_data_demo_4" AND m.meta_value != "")
AND (mi.meta_key = "my_test_data_demo_5" AND mi.meta_value = "")
ORDER BY m.`post_id` DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Run this query in my live server and demo server (It has a one-day-old data from live).

Demo server exec: 0,010 s.

Live server exec: 3,955 s.

When i remove "ORDER BY m.`post_id` DESC" - works fine and in live server (0,009).

Where is problem with order? Maybe the problem is somewhere else?

This is global problem, so don't need analyze query.

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_postmeta` (
    `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `post_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `meta_key` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `meta_value` longtext,
    PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
    KEY `post_id` (`post_id`),
    KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(191))
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: The `LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta mi` join can be replaced by `INNER` join, the result will be the same. The other two `LEFT` joins to `md` and `mf` are redundant and should be removed from the query.

Comment: MySQL version 5.5 in both servers.

Answer (score 0):

```
INDEX(post_id, meta_data)
```

And switch to InnoDB.

Get rid of the prefixing index, in one of these ways:

- Upgrade to 5.7
- `VARCHAR(191)` instead of 255
- `utf8` instead if `utf8mb4` (thereby not allowing Emoji or all of Chinese)

WP should get rid of `meta_id` and change to `PRIMARY KEY(post_id, meta_data)` and InnoDB.  That would make things even faster.  (But still, EAV schema sucks.)